# Can I give admin rights in Teamcity 8 to a certain active directory group?

Tags: active-directory, teamcity

I'm using Active Directory/LDAP to give access to certain AD groups to Teamcity (version 8). This is working for standard users, but is it possible to give admin rights to a particular group?

Answer (score 0):

Piers, it involves creating a TC group manually first. Take a look at this info: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/LDAP+Integration#LDAPIntegration-UserGroupMembership

Comment: Can I just map those AD groups to the administrator group in TC?